# How should I organize the React project to avoid react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs

The simplified structure is as following:

```
<context>
   <component />
<context>
```

context.tsx stores data and fetch functions:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(0)
const getData =async () => {
  const data = await get("/api")
  setData(data)
}
export default <Provider value={data, getData} />
```

inside the component, use useEffect to make request:

```
const {data, getData} = useContext(context)
useEffect(()=>{
     getData()
},[data]) // react-hooks/exhaustive-deps occurs here, it says I should put getData in the array. However, it will cause infinity loop.
return <div>{data}</div>
```

So, how can I reorganize the structure to avoid the warning? Btw, is it OK to make requests inside the context?

Comment: Your `getData` will probably change `data` on your dependency so it will trigger the effect again, you can either remove data from the useEffect's dependency or add some validation before triggering `getData` something like `if(!data) getData()`

Comment: React is warning you that your getData() can theoretically change. So to fix this you can specify you are using the current reference within your useEffect  with the useRef hook. See here for a sample use case: https://www.reactnative.express/react/hooks/useref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `useMemo` you can memoize the `getData` function, so that its reference never changes. This'll let you pass `exhaustive-deps`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(0);
const getData = useMemo(() => () => {
  const data = await get("/api");
  setData(data);
}, [setData]);
```

It's OK for `setData` to be in the dependency array here because state setter functions are stable.

> Btw, is it OK to make requests inside the context?

Sure, there's nothing inherently wrong with it.